# LDO LM317HV Problem With Output Voltage

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, ldo

I am designed a power supply. In my design i need 12v and 5v for get this voltages i use 2 LDO LM317HV as i show on the picture.

[image: Circuit]

V<sub>in</sub> is 48V. I need 0.3-0.2 A.

I get a stable 12v on my board but i can't get 5v on other HDO output instead of getting a 11.5V. I use the given formula to calculate HDOs outputs.

[image: Formula]

What can be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What voltage is Vin? Are you sure everything is soldered properly?

Comment: Also, you call this parallel in the question title, but it really isn't.

Comment: How much load is on 5V, or is there any?

Comment: The recommended value for R1 is 240 Ohms, as shown in all the example circuits in the datasheet.  With your 1.37K for R1, the the 100 uA current out of the adjustment terminal could become a significant part of the current through the voltage set resistors - not enough to cause your 11.5 V reading, but it may still be a concern.

Comment: The HV can require up to 12mA as a load current in order to regulate - you may need to provide a load resistor to make sure that happens

Comment: you label it "LDO", but the LM317 is pretty much the opposite of a **L**ow-*D*rop*o*ut regulator.

Comment: @Hearth Vin is 48V yes I soldered properly I was tested it.

Comment: @Hearh Yep my bad it is not parallel.

Comment: @Justme I don't connect any load no current on output.

Comment: How much current you need from the 5V or 12V?

Comment: The 12V one will be connected on MOSFET Driver Vcc

Comment: I need 0.3-0.2 amps

Comment: 5V one will be feed differantial opamps error opamps and Reference Voltage.

Comment: It would be less then 0.2 amps.

Comment: @MSB For 48 V in, a linear regulator is *not* the thing to use, especially not the LM317 (which requires a fairly substantial minimum load). Use a buck converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regulator needs enough current throught it for maintaining proper operation as a regulator, and you have no load.

TI LM317HV may required up to 12mA through it to work, typically 3.5mA.

Your 1.37k resistor won't even draw 1mA.

Since minimum current requied for proper operation is up to 12mA, it also means the regulator will waste 0.5W doing nothing at 48V input and will heat up.

Comment: I see. I want to test outputs before connect on load. For example the output of 5V LM317 connected to LDO that 5V to 3.3V regulator.

Comment: @MSB so add a resistor as load. Anyways, also add a heat sink: the LM317HV only comes in a TO-220 case, which has 23 °C/W thermal resistance to ambient and even if you only draw say 100 mA, you're making the device 99 °C hotter than the environment. (and if you assume the environment to be 21 °C warm, 120 °C):  I think you chose the wrong component to step down your voltage from 48 V. You'll want a switch-mode (buck) converter to make the "big" jump from 48 V down to 12 V, and then you can still use a linear regulator to go down to 5 V.

Comment: @MSB For 0.3 A at 12 V, your LM317 wastes power: (48 V - 12 V) · 0.3 A = 10.8 W get converted to heat. At the 23 °C/W, that means your LM317 gets hotter by 248 °C, and burns (or better, shuts itself down). So, you'll really need a *hefty* heat sink for that. I don't think you want to first spend money for an ancient linear regulator, and then spend even more money for a heat sink, potentially a fan that blows air over that heat sink, a separate voltage regulator for the fan…

Comment: @MarcusMüller I also think those are the wrong components for 48V input. Now generally the voltage adjust resistors are selected so that they provide the necessary minimum load, when there is a possibility of unknown or no load condition. If assumption is there is always enough load above minimum, the resistors can be higher in value to not waste power.

Comment: @Justme not to mention that for both 12 V and 5 V there's an abundance of fixed-voltage regulators that need no external resistors at all… but the real problem remains that for the load currents MSB mentions in their question's comments, you'd need to get rid of 10 W of heat. That's just way more than reasonable.

Comment: I guess i need a buck regulator for this type of applications.

Comment: @MSB Yes you do. However, fortunately, the original problem why the voltage is higher than expected is now solved.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If it's to drive a MOSFET gate or an Op Amp requiring <= 1mA, it's ok to use linear voltage regulator. But in this case he could just put a 50K resistor and  a Zener.

Comment: @MSB Yes I also highly recommend a buck regulator. But as I said, it depends on the current you really need. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Fredled Thanks. I will take a look for zener regulator design.

Comment: @MSB don't. You need a buck regulator anyways. So buck-regulate down to 12 V, and from these 12V, you can still linearly regulate down to 5 V, maybe with a fixed-output regulator instead of the ancient LM317. With a modern linear regulator from 12 V to 5 V, you would get a very nice and clean and high-rejection reference voltage (with the LM317, not so much. It's a really rudimentary regulator.)

Comment: Thanks for advices sir. My first time at using a LM317.

Comment: @MSB then this is an excellent moment to let it be the *last* experience with the LM317. It's really an ancient, and really not a good, regulator.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If he put a 50K resistor to feed the Zener, there is no risk and it will take only 1mA. 0.05W. I would use a buck regulator for, say, >5 mA.

Comment: @Fredled well, but then you would still need a buck for somewhere-close-to-but-above-5 V, and a linear regulator to get a clean analog reference. Nothing won by adding the zener regulator to the equation.

Comment: The datasheet for the LM317 shows a more expensive, lower minimum current LM117 using a 240 ohms resistor. That resistor provides a minimum load of 1.25V.240= 5.2mA. the LM317 has a 10mA minimum current so it needs a 120 ohms resistor.